# angular.copy() isn't creating an independent copy of an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I have an AngularJS app that uses a factory to load JSON data into objects.  Note that the following example is a VERY stripped down version of the real-life app.  The user objects use getter/setter methods to access their properties because the real-life app must handle more logic than a simple property assignment.  This means I cannot simply bind to the ngModel on the view - I have to use custom directives.  When I want to make edits to an object, I create a copy of the object in the controller, let users make changes to it in the view, and at the end either save or cancel those changes in the controller.  However, when I'm calling `angular.copy()`, the two objects still seem linked because changing data in one also changes data in the other.  Why is this?

Here is my JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/SqUu3/4/
Here is my view:

```
<div ng-app="foo" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(userID, user) in users">
        <span ng-if="inEditMode(userID)">
            <input type="text"
            ng-model="$name"
            ng-model-getter="editUsers[userID].getName()"
            ng-model-setter="editUsers[userID].setName($value)" />
            <button ng-click="saveChanges(userID)">Save</button>
            <button ng-click="setEditMode(editUsers[userID].getID(), false)">Cancel</button>
        </span>
        <span ng-if="!inEditMode(userID)">
            {{user.getName()}}
            <button ng-click="setEditMode(userID, true)">Edit</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
angular.module('foo', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope, UserFactory)
{
    // Maps user IDs to user objects
    // Using hash instead of array for fast access by ID
    $scope.users = UserFactory.load();
    // Maps IDs of users to copies of the respective user objects, used for editing
    $scope.editUsers = {};

    // Return whether or not we're editing the user
    $scope.inEditMode = function(userID)
    {
        return $scope.editUsers.hasOwnProperty(userID);
    };

    // Copy the changes made to the actual user object
    $scope.saveChanges = function(userID)
    {
        $scope.users[userID] = angular.copy($scope.editUsers[userID]);
        // Don't need the edit-copy, so get rid of it
        delete $scope.editUsers[userID];
    };

    // Turn edit mode on/off
    $scope.setEditMode = function(userID, inEditMode)
    {
        if(inEditMode)
        {
            // IN THEORY, this should create two independent copies of the same object
            $scope.editUsers[userID] = angular.copy($scope.users[userID]);

            /**
             * PROOF THESE ARE THE SAME OBJECTS:
             * This shouldn't affect the edit-copy in the view, but it does
             * Note that I am only doing this next call to prove that angular.copy() 
             * isn't giving me a new, independent copy of the user object
             */
            $scope.users[userID].setName("WHY IS THIS THE SAME");
        }
        else
        {
            // We are effecively canceling the changes we've made
            delete $scope.editUsers[userID];
        }
    };
})
```

The interesting part is the `IN THEORY...` line (line 30 in my JSFiddle).  This isn't creating an independent object.

Comment: Could you try angular.copy($scope.users[userID], $scope.editUsers[userID]); type syntax? The docs are not entirely clear, but it sounds like if destination is not passed in then its not returned either.

Comment: why do you need the `ng-model-getter`/`ng-model-setter`, the closure in the `User` factory, and a whole other stuff? your code seems like it's doing a lot more than it should.

Comment: This is a VERY stripped down version of the app I'm actually working on.  Getter/Setters are necessary because there's a lot more logic being done than simple property assignments.  The `UserFactory`, in real life, makes an AJAX call, which loads JSON data into the `User` objects.  I simplify all that by hardcoding JSON data into `rawUserData`.  @aet I believe your method and mine do the same exact thing.  If you don't specify a destination, then `angular.copy()` returns the copy.

Comment: @EliranMalka No, I meant `$scope.users[userID].setName` because I am just trying to demonstrate that `$scope.users` and `$scope.editUsers` seem to still be linked somehow.

Comment: how is that demonstrating this?

Comment: I made a copy of the user object and stored it in `$scope.editUsers[userID]`.  I then called `setName` on `$scope.users[userID]`, but this is still changing the object in `$scope.editUsers[userID]`.

Comment: You could always do var x = angular.copy(y, {}); For some reason I still use $.extend for this most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

The `name` and `id` properties were bounded incorrectly as private properties in the `User` factory, so `name` could not be accessed in the view (and I assume it broke the two-way binding).

Bind them to the factory object (using `this`) and it should be resolved.

```js
angular.module('foo', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope, UserFactory)
{
    // Maps user IDs to user objects
    // Using hash instead of array for fast access by ID
    $scope.users = UserFactory.load();
    // Maps IDs of users to copies of the respective user objects, used for editing
    $scope.editUsers = {};
    
    // Return whether or not we're editing the user
    $scope.inEditMode = function(userID)
    {
        return $scope.editUsers.hasOwnProperty(userID);
    };
    
    // Copy the changes made to the actual user object
    $scope.saveChanges = function(userID)
    {
        $scope.users[userID] = angular.copy($scope.editUsers[userID]);
        // Don't need the edit-copy, so get rid of it
        delete $scope.editUsers[userID];
    };

    // Turn edit mode on/off
    $scope.setEditMode = function(userID, inEditMode)
    {
        if(inEditMode)
        {
            // IN THEORY, this should create two independent copies of the same object
            $scope.editUsers[userID] = angular.copy($scope.users[userID]);
            
            /**
             * PROOF THESE ARE THE SAME OBJECTS:
             * This shouldn't affect the edit-copy in the view, but it does
             */
            $scope.users[userID].setName("WHY IS THIS THE SAME");
        }
        else
        {
            // We are effecively canceling the changes we've made
            delete $scope.editUsers[userID];
        }
    };
})
.factory('UserFactory', function(User)
{
    return {
        load: function()
        {
            // Simulate a JSON response with user data
            var rawUserData = [
                {id: 1, name: "Dave"},
                {id: 2, name: "Brian"}
            ];
            var userIDsToObjects = {};
            
            for(var userIter = 0;userIter < rawUserData.length;userIter++)
            {
                userIDsToObjects[rawUserData[userIter].id] = new User(rawUserData[userIter].id, rawUserData[userIter].name);
            }
            
            return userIDsToObjects;
        }
    }
})
.factory('User', function()
{
    return function(newID, newName)
    {
        this.getID = function()
        {
            return this.id;
        };
        
        this.getName = function()
        {
            return this.name;
        };
        
        this.setID = function(newID)
        {
            this.id = +newID;
        };
        
        this.setName = function(newName)
        {
            this.name = newName;
        };
        
        var self = this;
        // var id;
        // var name;
        
        (function()
         {
             self.setID(newID);
             self.setName(newName);
         })();
    }
})
.directive('ngModelGetter', function()
{
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        //controller: "ctrl",
        link:  function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl)
        {
            var getExpression = attrs.ngModelGetter;
            
            function updateViewValue(newValue, oldValue)
            {
                if(newValue != ngModelCtrl.$viewValue)
                {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(newValue);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }
                
                var updateExpression = attrs.ngModel + "=" + getExpression;
                scope.$eval(updateExpression);
            }
            
            updateViewValue();
            
            scope.$watch(getExpression, updateViewValue);
        }
    };
})
.directive('ngModelSetter', function()
{
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        //controller: "ctrl",
        link:  function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl)
        {
            var setExpression = attrs.ngModelSetter;
            
            function updateModelValue(e)
            {
                scope.$value = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
                scope.$eval(setExpression);
                delete scope.$value;
            }
            
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, updateModelValue);
        }
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="foo" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(userID, user) in users">
        <span ng-if="inEditMode(userID)">
            <input type="text"
            ng-model="$name"
            ng-model-getter="editUsers[userID].getName()"
            ng-model-setter="editUsers[userID].setName($value)" />
            <button ng-click="saveChanges(userID)">Save</button>
            <button ng-click="setEditMode(editUsers[userID].getID(), false)">Cancel</button>
        </span>
        <span ng-if="!inEditMode(userID)">
            {{user.getName()}}
            <button ng-click="setEditMode(userID, true)">Edit</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd prefer the properties to remain private and only be get/set using public methods.  Is this possible?  Obviously, it's not natively possible in angular, which is why I have the `ng-model-getter` and `ng-model-setter` directives.

Comment: what is the benefit in keeping them private? you can still use getters and setters regardless.

Comment: Simply for abstraction.  I'm still confused why Angular is having problems with this.  I mean, the `getter/setter` methods work fine on private properties for displaying info in the view.  Why does this suddenly break it?

Comment: you refer to `$name` in the view, which is expected to be exposed on the user object (you're in the `ng-repeat`'s scope, so each user would have to expose a `name` in its model)

Comment: `$name` doesn't actually refer to the property called `name` in the `User` object.  You could rename it to `$FAKEVARTHATDOESNOTEXIST` if you wanted.  It's simply a placeholder in the `ng-model` directive, which we must include to get the ngModelController in the `ng-model-getter` and `ng-model-setter` directives.

Comment: oh ok. i don't get it than :)

Comment: Haha that makes 2 of us

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for angular.copy, if you do not specify destination, it is set to source.

```
  if (!destination) {
    destination = source;
```

In the end, it just:

```
 return destination;
```

Comment: It looks like `destination` is set to `source`, but if `source` is an object, then `destination` is reset:`destination = copy(source, {});`.  In other words, it looks like setting setting `destination` accomplishes the same thing as not and expecting a return value.