# angular.copy and angular.extend - copies still referencing the original array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I checked SO and found this question [angular.copy() isn't creating an independent copy of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22946820/angular-copy-isnt-creating-an-independent-copy-of-an-object) - The title describes the issue i'm having, though the answers didn't help.

I am attempting to copy an array, broadcast an event with that array and then clear the source array. In doing this my copy is also empty. I can verify that the copy works in as much as my destination is filled by commenting out code that clears the source.

I have tried both `angular.copy` and `angular.extend` (ensuring i have the parameters the correct way around, as they are opposite for these 2 methods)

I have also tried with arrays that are on the `scope` rather than just local variables too - this made no difference

The parts of code that are using this are:

```
    dz.on('queuecomplete', function () {
        console.log('queue complete')
        console.log(uploadedFiles)
        var filesOut = [];
        angular.copy(uploadedFiles, filesOut);
        $rootScope.$broadcast('file.upload.complete', { files: filesOut });
        scope.uploadComplete = true;
        scope.completeMessage = 'Wooohoo!'
        resetAll();
    });

    function resetAll() {
        dz.removeAllFiles();
        scope.hasTooMany = false;
        scope.hasBadTypes = false;
        scope.manualUpload = false;
        hasHadErrors = false;
        // If i comment this out then my listener (below) shows all files
        // if i leave this as-is then both source and dest arrays are empty
        uploadedFiles = [];
        scope.$apply();
    }
```

In another controller I am listening to the `$broadcast`

```
var filesUploaded = $scope.$on('file.upload.complete', function (event, data) {
    console.log('files uploaded:')
    // if 'uploadedFiled = []' is not commented out then data.files is an empty array
    console.log(data);
});
```

As mentioned, i've tried this with extend too.

What am i missing? Or am i expecting something that the methods aren't designed for?

Comment: Hi Darren please see here http://jsbin.com/canajodinube/1/edit copy not referencing original array

Comment: Thanks. Yep, i see it there and also see on the angularjs docs site it's independent - though have no idea why mine isn't.. Can you see anything in the code above as to why?

Comment: can you check what you get if you put that after angular.copy(uploadedFiles, filesOut); console.log(uploadedFiles)